# How can I avoid duplicate processing of vertices in the priorityqueue with Dijkstra?

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra

So everytime a neighbors is discovered with an improved distance, it is added to the priorityqueue with the new distance (so it can be used in the right order). This means however that the old entry with the old distance remains in the queue and is processed later on.

This does not seem to be an issue, since all neighbors will already have the optimized value from the previous pass, so `newDistance < neighbor.totalDistance()` will never be true, right?

I'm wondering though, can it be avoided altogether?

Current implementation is:

```
class App {
    record Node(String name) {}

    record Edge(Node node, int cost) { }

    record NodeWrapper(Node n, int totalDistance, NodeWrapper prev) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Node, List<Edge>> graph = new HashMap<>();
        Node s = new Node("S");
        Node a = new Node("A");
        Node b = new Node("B");
        Node c = new Node("C");
        Node d = new Node("D");

        graph.put(s, List.of(new Edge(a, 20), new Edge(d,10)));
        graph.put(a, List.of(new Edge(s, 20), new Edge(d,20), new Edge(b, 20), new Edge(c, 50)));
        graph.put(b, List.of(new Edge(a, 20), new Edge(c,10)));
        graph.put(c, List.of(new Edge(a, 50), new Edge(b,10), new Edge(d, 50)));
        graph.put(d, List.of(new Edge(s, 10), new Edge(a,20), new Edge(c, 50)));

        Map<Node, NodeWrapper> nodeWrappers = new HashMap<>();
        PriorityQueue<NodeWrapper> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt(NodeWrapper::totalDistance));
        Set<Node> visited = new HashSet<>();

        NodeWrapper startWrapper = new NodeWrapper(s, 0, new NodeWrapper(s, 0, null));
        nodeWrappers.put(s, startWrapper);
        queue.add(startWrapper);

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            NodeWrapper current = queue.poll();
            visited.add(current.n());

            for (Edge edge : graph.get(current.n())) {
                if (visited.contains(edge.node)) {
                    continue;
                }

                int newDistance = current.totalDistance() + edge.cost();
                NodeWrapper neighbor = nodeWrappers.get(edge.node());
                if (neighbor == null || newDistance < neighbor.totalDistance()) {
                    var x = new NodeWrapper(edge.node, newDistance, current);
                    nodeWrappers.put(edge.node(), x);
                    queue.offer(x);
                }
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Node, NodeWrapper> nodeNodeWrapperEntry : nodeWrappers.entrySet()) {
            System.out.printf("%s: %d %s%n", nodeNodeWrapperEntry.getKey().name(), nodeNodeWrapperEntry.getValue().totalDistance(), nodeNodeWrapperEntry.getValue().prev().n().name());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `[When a neighbour] is discovered with an improved distance, it is added to the priorityqueue with the new distance [and] the old entry [and] distance remains in the queue…` *Dijkstra's algorithm* ("[many variants](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm)") or *the procedure presented*? [`java.util.PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#method-summary) got it wrong offering no general *update priority value*, not even a [replace top priority item](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.heapreplace).

Comment: Most of the redundant processing could be avoided using `if (!visited.add(current.n())) continue;`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this graph:

```
//   S--10--A 
//   |      |
//   25     5
//   |      |
//   D--5---B        

    Map<Node, List<Edge>> graph = new HashMap<>();
    Node s = new Node("S");
    Node a = new Node("A");
    Node b = new Node("B");
    Node d = new Node("D");

    graph.put(s, List.of(new Edge(a, 10), new Edge(d,25)));
    graph.put(a, List.of(new Edge(s, 10), new Edge(b, 5)));
    graph.put(b, List.of(new Edge(a, 5),  new Edge(d,5)));
    graph.put(d, List.of(new Edge(s, 25), new Edge(b,5)));
```

There will be a shorter path from `S` to `D` (via `A` `B`) that needs the second part of the if.

Comment: The thing is, after S-A-B-D is discovered, I still have the old entries in the queue [B->D 25, S->D 20], because every cheaper path will be put into the priorityqueue.